# Hover event with list items not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to build a menu, using `li` tags wrapped in `a href` tags, to create the menu items; I have a jQuery `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` function, which don't work. As the function don't work I've replaced the code with a simple alert, but that doesn't seem to do anything either:

html:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu" style="text-align: left;padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;font-family: menu_local_font; color: #ffffff;font-size: 30px;padding: 20px; height: 40px">

    <a href="http://vaste-wouter/BuitengewoonGrondig2/">
       <li class="menuitem" style="float:left;;overflow:hidden;height: 40px;padding-right:30px;text-decoration:none;color: #d3005f;">
           De Vergeten Peer<br><br>test
       </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".menuitem").mouseover(function(){    
        alert('over');  
        //$(this).stop().animate({height:'150px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

    $(".menuitem").mouseout(function(){
    //    $(this).stop().animate({height:'40px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not a valid html. You can't have an `a` inside a ul. The same goes for the `li` you can't wrap them with `a`.

Comment: Once you change the html to be valid, this shouldn't have a problem running.

Comment: @drip You are wrong. You are allowed to wrap an `<a>` tag in an `<li>` tag like so: `<li><a>...</a></li>`. OP: you just need to flip your tags around.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek `wrap` means to wrap an element with something, not to add something in it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Valid list:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menuitem"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="menuitem"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="menuitem"><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Inline styles are not best practice. You need to separate content from design.

OR

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
   <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
    $(function(){
        $("ul.menu > li").mouseover(function(){    
            alert('over'); 
        });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause** You have errors in your HTML hierarchy structure. It  should be:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="URL">Text</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But you have this

```
<ul>
  **<a href="URL">**
      <li>
         Text<
      </li>
  **</a>**
</ul>
```

**RECOMMENDATIONS:**
I dont know if you are only testing, but remember that it is important to put all your styles in the CSS, avoid to use style="" tag. Also you have severa colon symbols (;) duplicated, remove them.
**CODE:**
Here is your code running: http://goo.gl/P5vRtG